# Invoking WCF service using PHP with SOAP 1.2 gives an error

Tags: php, wcf, soap1.2

I am trying to access a WCF service using the PHP soap client.
I keep receiving the error: "Error Fetching http headers"
I tried increasing the default_socket_time as well.
I need to use basic authentication as well as parameters for the methods when accessing the services.
Following is my PHP code. I am unable to change the server configurations.

```
<?php
    $wsdl = "https://example.com/NewServer/Services/WCFServices.svc?wsdl";

$url=$wsdl;
$svc = 'WCFServices';
$func = 'getValId';
$username = "admin";
$password = "admin";


$apiauth =array('UserName'=>$username,'Password'=>$password);
$authHeader = new SoapHeader('https://tempuri.org/', 'AuthHeader', $apiauth);

$client = new SoapClient($url, array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2, 
                                     'exceptions' => true,
                                     'trace' => true);

try
{ 
    ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 600);
    $client->__setSoapHeaders($authHeader);
    $info = $client->__soapCall($func, array('extRef' => 'ABCD'));
      var_dump($info);
} 
catch (SoapFault $fault) 
{ 
    var_dump($fault);
      $xml=$fault->faultstring;
    die;
}
?>
```

Guidance into correct path would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WCF service which I was invoking had both HTTP and basic bindings available.
So I invoked the basic endpoint which uses SOAP 1.1 version. Posting the code as it will be useful to someone in the future.

```
<?php
    class WsseAuthHeader extends SoapHeader 
    {
        private $wss_ns = 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd';
        function __construct($user, $pass, $ns = null) 
        {    
            if ($ns) 
            {        
                $this->wss_ns = $ns;    
            }    
    
            $auth = new stdClass();    
    
            $auth->Username = new SoapVar($user, XSD_STRING, NULL, $this->wss_ns, NULL, $this->wss_ns);     
            $auth->Password = new SoapVar($pass, XSD_STRING, NULL, $this->wss_ns, NULL, $this->wss_ns);    
            $username_token = new stdClass();    
            $username_token->UsernameToken = new SoapVar($auth, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, NULL, $this->wss_ns, 'UsernameToken', $this->wss_ns);     
            $security_sv = new SoapVar(        
                                    new SoapVar($username_token, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, NULL, $this->wss_ns, 'UsernameToken', $this->wss_ns),        
                                    SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, NULL, $this->wss_ns, 'Security', $this->wss_ns);    
    
            parent::__construct($this->wss_ns, 'Security', $security_sv, true);
        }
    }
    
    $options = array( 
                'soap_version'    => SOAP_1_1, 
                'exceptions'      => true, 
                'trace'           => 1, 
                'wdsl_local_copy' => true);
    
    
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    
    $wsse_header = new WsseAuthHeader($username, $password);    
    
    $client = new SoapClient('https://ServerName/WCFService.svc?wsdl', $options); 
    $client->__setSoapHeaders(array($wsse_header));
    $client->__setLocation('https://ServerName/WCFService.svc/basicSecurity');
    
    try
    {
        $params = array('param1' => 'xxxx');
        $phpresponse = $client->__soapCall('methodname', array('parameters' => $params));
    
        var_dump($phpresponse);
        echo "</b><BR/><BR/>";
    }
    catch(Exception $e) 
    { 
        echo "<h2>Exception Error!</h2></b>"; 
        echo $e->getMessage(); 
    }
    
    ?>
```